# Bonferroni's inequality proof

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I'm having a hard time proving this inequality:

$P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k\right) \le\ \sum_{k=1}^nP(A_k) -  \sum_{i < j} P(A_i\cap\ A_j) + \sum_{i<j<k}P(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k)$

So I started by letting $n=3$ which is true as it follows on from $P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$

Then assuming that $n=m$ is true:

$P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{m+1} A_k\right) = P\ ((\bigcup_{k=1}^{m}A_k) \cup A_{m+1})$

Let $B=\bigcup_{k=1}^{m}A_k$ then:

$P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{m+1} A_k\right) = P\ (B \cup A_{m+1})= P(B)+ P(A_{m+1}) - P(B \cap A_{m+1})$

And this is where I am stuck I don't know how to go forwards with the proof, I've tried a few different methods but they all didn't work out. Any ideas?

Comment: You might have better luck if you understand what the inequality is telling you; you're "over correcting" for what the actual probability of the union is. Try starting with one element. Then two elements. You're constantly setting upper and lower bound limits alternatively.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_k$ be the indicator random variable of event $A_k$. Note that $$\mathrm{LHS} = \operatorname{E}\left[1-\prod(1-X_k)\right] \text{ and }\mathrm{RHS} = \operatorname{E}\left[\sum X_k - \sum_{i<j} X_iX_j + \sum_{i<j<k}X_iX_jX_k\right].$$ It is enough to show that $$1-\prod(1-x_k)\leq \sum x_k - \sum_{i<j} x_ix_j + \sum_{i<j<k}x_ix_jx_k \text{ for all }x_i\in\{0,1\}.$$

One can use induction on $n$ to prove the above inequality.

Hint: consider two cases $x_n=0$ (use induction hypothesis) and $x_n=1$ (where $\mathrm{LHS}=\mathrm{RHS}=1$).